# Question on partition of positive integer

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

I know only basic about partition of a natural number like $p(0)=1$, $p(1)=1$,

$p(2)=2 $ that is $$2=1+1$$

$$2=2$$ and similarly $p(3)=3 $ as

$$3=1+1+1$$

$$3=2+1$$

$$3=3$$ and for further reading of partition of natural number is [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#:~:text=In%20number%20theory%20and%20combinatorics,the%20sum%20becomes%20a%20composition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#:%7E:text=In%20number%20theory%20and%20combinatorics,the%20sum%20becomes%20a%20composition.))

I am solving a problem, for that I need all such partition of natural number n such that it does not include $1's.$ For example for $n=3$ there is only one such partition that is $3=3$. similarly for $n=4$ there are two such partitions that is $4=2+2$ and $4=4.$

**Question**

So I general for a given arbitrary natural number $n$ how many such partitions exists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form for what you are looking for.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I believe that it is  $$  n! \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} $$ but i am not able to prove it can you help me

Comment: Your formula gives $2$ for $n=3$ and $9$ for $n=4$, which does not match your observations...

Answer (score 2):

There are $p(n) -  p(n-1)$ such partitions; equivalently the number of partitions which have at least one $1$ is just $p(n-1)$ because by removing the one you get a partition of $n-1$.

The formula you wrote down in the comments is the number of derangement of $n$ objects which is different so it’s not clear what you really want. To compare these numbers:

The number of derangements is the number of elements in the symmetric group $S_n$ with no fixed point; the number of partitions without one is the number of conjugacy classes of elements in $S_n$ without fixed points. These are very related but clearly not the same; the first grows faster than exponentially and the second grows slower than exponentially.

Comment: Thanks for answering, basically i want to find the number of such partitions without one and its conjugacy classes of elements in $S_n$.

Comment: @user98984 Can we find out the number of elements in $S_n$ corresponding to  partition $P(n)-P(n-1)$?

Comment: @Mathematicslearner As I said in my answer the number of elements is equal to the number of “derangements” and is given by the formula in your comment and is proved in many cases including Wikipedia (search for derangements)